# Does the CSS property "text-transform" affect SEO results?

Tags: html, css, search, seo, ranking

I am building a site with a ton of 1999 style capitalization of navigation and headings. I have been simply adding in the text content as it appears (capitalized), but the other designer on the project insists on using lower case text in his HTML and capitalizing it with an applied style:

```
.tedious {text-transform:uppercase;}
```

I understand the argument of separation of style from content, but in this case it really doesn't matter because I personally will not maintain the site, nor do I ever imagine that the client will need to un-capitalize all of this text. The question is: 1. will search engines pay any attention at all to capitalization of text in a document and 2. would a crawler go so far as to read my style sheet and look for such things (me thinks not). I know that BOLD, STRONG, EM, etc have a (diminishing) effect on SEO so I can imagine a scenario where CAPS would, but have never heard of anyone actually claiming, let alone confirming this.

Digging this site the last few months. First post.

Comment: Since this is you first question, welcome to SO :)

Comment: IIRC, Google does read style sheets, e.g. to check whether text is being hidden using CSS. However, I don't see any reason for them to even consider checking for text-transform. It doesn't change the message, and that is all Google cares about. I also doubt that bold, strong, and em have a *diminishing* effect on SEO. From my personal experience, quite the opposite is the case, as long as they are used sparingly. Then again, nobody can claim to know for sure what Google does (even inside Google, only few people know all the details), and whatever it does is subject to permanent change anyway.

Comment: I can't find an answer, too, but perhaps Google's forum at http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters is a more appropiate place to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will only effect what is shown in the search results, you colleagues work will show as lower case in the results.

You mentioned separation of style from content, but i'm not convinced that text-transform is a style really, it's a change of content, i'm sure some people would argue the other side though.

Comment: Depends what you consider to be content. If it's all-caps for the sole sake of presentation, then that sounds to me like it's presentational, and should be in CSS. My preferred style for something like this would be to make the nav links capitalized naturally - "Home" - and then apply all-caps in the style if I *really* cared that much.

Comment: If you really want all-caps in every browser, then you should write it all-caps in your markup. Visitors with browsers without CSS-capabilities (like Lynx) or people browsing with CSS turned off (they do exist) will also see all-caps.

Comment: Excellent point, ALL CAPS in search results can be a bit of an eyesore. thx

Answer (score 3):

if i was a search engine - I wouldn't care about casing.  I would care about the content.

From a human readability standpoint - upper case isn't as easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I was taught at school that all proper nouns (eg names and names of places) should begin with capital letters.

How would Google know whether I was talking about reading (as in a book) or Reading (as in the town of Reading, Berkshire), without taking into account the capitalisation? I would argue that capitalisation is definitely a semantic indicator rather than simply a case of aesthetics, and is therefore one factor that could be used for SEO.

As noted elsewhere, Google clearly does have knowledge of the CSS being used to render a page (eg Google can spot black-hat techniques such as white text on a white background).

So if capitalisation (or lack of) is a relevant SEO factor, can the CSS text-transform (or lack of) value also be an SEO factor?
Yes - because Google considers page speed to be an important factor. Text that doesn't need to be transformed by CSS will display faster.

Comment: How about "font-variant-caps"?

Answer (score 0):

Answer from google:

I don't think we'd do anything special with all-caps headings, but it feels like the kind of thing you'd want to do in CSS instead of in the content, since it's more about styling.

https://mobile.twitter.com/JohnMu/status/1438159561391751170?s=19